# Horizontal lines on ceiling, roof leaking

Tags: ceiling, roof, leaking

My bedroom's ceiling has been leaking (*more like dripping*) when it's raining or snow melting, and I highly doubt that the old TV satellite dish caused the roof leaking. (*Pic 1*)

What troubles me more  is that I noticed there is another spot with thin horizontal lines on the ceiling and it’s right above where I usually sit and work. (*Pic 2*)

I have an inclined roof and the leaking spot  is located slightly higher than pic 2's spot.

Can anyone tell me what might be the cause of this kind of line?

*the dark spot is caused by my phone's camera*

[image: Leaking Spot]

[image: Another group of lines on ceiling]

Comment: Water from leak running along (and through) joints in drywall (thus the lines.) The leak can be anywhere higher than the location of the leaking below - not often directly above, as if it runs sideways to find a weak point that's where it will pop out. Can easily travel 10's of feet along the bottom of a rafter.

Comment: In the first picture, is that the ceiling on the left and walls on the right, looking into a corner? If not, I'm _very_ confused by what I'm seeing there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ecnerwal is spot on.

While you figure out how to fix this poke a few holes through the ceiling and place a bucket underneath so the water can get through. It may seem worse initially but remember the water has to go somewhere. If it isn't coming through the ceiling then it's soaking into the drywall and insulation and the extra weight might bring the entire ceiling down to say nothing of damaging even more.

Jonathan

Comment: Absolutely this as the first step.  My in-laws had a leaking AC drain in the attic, and it slowly destroyed 10sqft of ceiling, which came crashing down in one lump in the middle of the night.  No one had any idea it was pooling up there until that moment.